# React | render html tag in jsx

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

How do render string along with html tag in react. I just want to add redirecting in 10 seconds to next line but I'm getting [object object] instead.

```
tip={"Please wait!" +<br/ >+"Redirecing in 10 seconds..."}
```

[image] 
**DEMO:**
[CodeSandbox Link](https://codesandbox.io/s/sad-waterfall-ytyw9)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [the Doc](https://ant.design/components/spin/#API) :

`Tip` should be a `string` , use `\n` for line breaks and add `whiteSpace: "break-spaces` to the style of the `Spin`:

```
<Spin tip={"Please wait! \n Redirecing in 10 seconds..."} style={{ whiteSpace: "break-spaces"}}>
```

```js
ReactDOM.render(
  <antd.Spin tip={"Please wait! \n Redirecing in 10 seconds..."} style={{ whiteSpace: "break-spaces"}}>
    <antd.Alert
      message="Alert message title"
      description="Further details about the context of this alert."
      type="info"
    />
  </antd.Spin>,
  document.getElementById("container")
);
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/antd/4.0.2/antd.min.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/antd/4.0.2/antd.min.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try like this:

```
<Spin tip={<span><br />"Loading..."</span>}>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try add "\n" into the string

Answer (score 0):

You should put everything inside a jsx tag without quotes and concatenation, like this:

```
tip={<span>Please wait!<br/ >Redirecing in 10 seconds...</span>}
```

Answer (score 0):

It might be something like `<Spin tip={[<br />, "Loading..."]}>`.

Answer (score 0):

You can not send HTML tags inside Spin component of ant design spin prop.

It will always consider it a string and will not render the HTML.

I think this helps to prevent unnecessary code into our app.